# Konqueror randomly showing same search results

Tags: kubuntu, konqueror

In Konqueror I use startpage.com as searchengine. Recently I began to notice that no matter what I search for the searchengine is randomly showing the same results page. I clean the cache at every shutdown, I've removed and reinstalled Konqueror and still the same page is shown randomly. I believe it is not an intentional action on the part of startpage.com. Since malware is very unusual on Linux I believe I can rule that out too. So I wonder how do I get rid of the page.

This is the relevant part of the page shown:

[image]

Comment: You could also include the search wordS.

Comment: Search words are irrelevant. It can happen with any query.

Comment: Since you've asked for it: it just happened again with the query linux bridge subnets

Comment: I'd check in the advanced search settings if there's no phrase set that would dominate search results.

Comment: I don't see a setting like that,

Comment: Each time this page appears Startpage.com presents a cookie named in_array. It does not show up on other searchresults, i suspect it to be Javascript related.